# Customizing styles

Tags: java, android, themes

To customize a standard style, I use the following XML file :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

The problem is that Eclipse tells me that the "windowNoTitle" attribute doesnot exist, but I have cut & pasted it from the example shown in the official web site for styles and themes indicated in the Android dev doc.

How can I modify this standard code to have no title bar?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add `android:` prefix before attriibute name, also you need use valid syntax for the link to parent theme ike this:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I already tried to add "android:". But the attribute "windowNoTitle" was not part of the list shown by the IDE.

Comment: There is no matter, I have tried and it compiles just fine. Try it and inform me on results

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `.NoTitleBar` at the end so you don't need extra `style item`.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoTitleBar" />
```

Comment: The "Holo.Light.NoTitleBar" theme doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for fullscreen: 
`<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>`

 And it doesn't have Title Bar. Hopefully this helps.